# How to disable query execution plan caching per query in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there any chance to disable query execution plan caching using entity framework?

I know that in objectQuery i could disable it per query: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.enableplancaching(v=vs.110).aspx)
But I don't see such option in dbQuery.

I also know that there are interceptors in EF 6 and I Could simply attach option (recompile) but I can't find solution how to attach it only to one exact query not to every query in context.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to disable LinqToEntity query plan caching? You do know that this is purely for the SQL generation and not the SQL Server query plan...right?

Comment: Sure I understand that EF is for sql generation and it was designed to be cross database. But still looking for solution to my problem.

Comment: @Aron - why does it matters if he wants to disable caching? For one, I'm also trying to disable caching for one specific query because I'm getting incorrect results when executing multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Entity Framework's 6's `ObjectQuery.EnablePlanCaching` - where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124984/entity-frameworks-6s-objectquery-enableplancaching-where-is-it) I once wrote this:

```
    var optimizedQuery = DisablePlanCaching(query).AsNoTracking();
```

to use these extensions methods:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> DisablePlanCaching<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var objectQuery = GetObjectQuery(query);
        if (objectQuery != null)
        {
            objectQuery.EnablePlanCaching = false;
        }
        return query;
    }

    private static ObjectQuery GetObjectQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var objectQuery = query as ObjectQuery<T>;
        if (objectQuery == null)
        {
            var dbQuery = query as DbQuery<T>;
            if (dbQuery != null)
            {
                objectQuery = DbQueryToObjectQuery(dbQuery);
            }
        }
        return objectQuery;
    }

    public static ObjectQuery<T> DbQueryToObjectQuery<T>(DbQuery<T> dbQuery)
    {
        FieldInfo internalQueryField = dbQuery.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery"));
        var internalQuery = internalQueryField?.GetValue(dbQuery);
        FieldInfo objectQueryField = internalQuery?.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery"));
        var objectQuery = objectQueryField?.GetValue(internalQuery) as ObjectQuery<T>;
        return objectQuery;
    }
```