# Entity Framework's 6's `ObjectQuery.EnablePlanCaching` - where is it?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) explains that query plan caching can be deactivated by setting `EnablePlanCaching` to `false` on the `ObjectQuery`, and also that it is enabled by default in EF6.

Alas, EF6 doesn't have an `ObjectQuery`, the `DbSet`'s give you `DbQuery`s.

I don't think I can get an `ObjectQuery` from the `DbQuery`, and I certainly don't want to use the old `ObjectContext`. So is that it or is there a way to disable plan caching in EF6?

Comment: EF6 has DbContext and DbSet and does not support OBjectQuery anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extension method that will let you get an ObjectQuery from the DbSet

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var query = ctx.Products;
    query.GetObjectQuery().EnablePlanCaching = false;
    var list = query.ToList();
}


namespace Z.EntityFramework.Plus
{
    internal static partial class InternalExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>An IQueryable&lt;TEntity&gt; extension method that get the ObjectQuery from the query.</summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements of the query.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="query">The query to get the ObjectQuery from.</param>
        /// <returns>The ObjectQuery from the query.</returns>
        internal static ObjectQuery<T> GetObjectQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            // CHECK for ObjectQuery
            var objectQuery = query as ObjectQuery<T>;
            if (objectQuery != null)
            {
                return objectQuery;
            }

            // CHECK for DbQuery
            var dbQuery = query as DbQuery<T>;

            if (dbQuery == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Oops! A general error has occurred. Please report the issue including the stack trace to our support team: info@zzzprojects.com");
            }

            var internalQueryProperty = dbQuery.GetType().GetProperty("InternalQuery", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var internalQuery = internalQueryProperty.GetValue(dbQuery, null);
            var objectQueryContextProperty = internalQuery.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectQuery", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var objectQueryContext = objectQueryContextProperty.GetValue(internalQuery, null);

            objectQuery = objectQueryContext as ObjectQuery<T>;

            return objectQuery;
        }
    }
}
```